# Как сделать "песочницу" для записей базы данных asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, localstorage

У меня есть новостной портал с всеми данными в бд. Нужно сделать пустую, локальную "базу данных" в которую пользователь вводил бы что-угодно: добавлял, удалял новости, писал комментарии, но это было бы только на его компьютере если он включил режим песочницы. Всё уже реализовано для обычной SQL базы данных, но как это сделать для "локального хранилища" я без понятия

Comment: а почему надо хранить именно локально?

Comment: такое тз было, тут ничего не могу с этим сделать

Comment: имело смысл тогда строить интерфейс, используя какой-нить js фреймворк, чтобы данные получать и от сервера и с локального хранилища в json-е каком нить. В целом, картинки же вы, к примеру, в локальном хранилище не сможете хранить, его объем, емнип, 5мбайт

Comment: Черт, так и думал ,что будут с этим траблы, придется вообще архитектуру сносить.

Comment: И все таки что такое "локальная" сервер при существующей свой БД вполне может эмулироваьт для клиента локальное хранение. Но да, без сервера оно не заработает. И да, на локальные хранилища есть серъезные ограничеия и реализовать это целиком на клиенте в браузере проблематично, а это значит что для действительно локального хранения вы должны делать вообще не web приложение а десктопное

Comment: @Mike об ограничениях знаю. Может кэш использовать?

Comment: @AshenOne И как его использовать. сейчас он есть, а завтра браузер посчитал что к данным долго не обращались и место под новые данные нужно и потер

Comment: @Mike тут важна именно работа кэша "на день" , чтобы удовлетворить потребности тимлидов, которые задают разныме т.з. новичкам.

Comment: В общем на кеш я бы не полагался ни при каких обстоятельствах

Comment: @Mike других вариантов не вижу

Comment: кстати, вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480879/chrome-webkit-websql-database-maximum-file-size написано, что если запросить большую БД то браузер просто спросит у пользователя можно или нет. И я бы все таки перечитал внимательно ТЗ собственная БД пользователя и хранимая именно локально в браузере, разные вещи

Comment: @Mike все что сказали - сделать как бы "песочницу" для того чтобы юзер мог делать с ней "что-угодно", сделать площадку для экспериментов, главное чтоб она была локальной и чтоб пользователь не заморачивался с установкой дополнительного ПО

Comment: тогда уточните у постановщика на сколько локальной она должна быть. должна ли она работать без доступа к сети

Comment: @Mike нашел решение - делать через Веб-хранилище

Comment: Это localStorage что ли ? Ну там до 10 Мб https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values